# Why can't I get this stringFromDate code to work?

Tags: ios

The following code is supposed to format the datestamp from coredata entity "**DIncome**"

But I'm getting the `following error`, which I'm pretty sure has something to do with this code.

> -"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'NSDate *'"-

```
DIncome *dIncome = [dailyIncomeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDateFormatter *formateDateString = [NSDateFormatter alloc];
[formateDateString setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [formateDateString stringFromDate:dIncome.datestamp];

NSLog(@"%@" "This is your date log", formattedDateString);
```

Thanks a bunch for your time and help!

Comment: check your `dIncome.datestamp`?? make sure is it proper or not ?? also must mach `dIncome.datestamp` date formate to `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Check with this NSLog(@"%@", dIncome.datestamp) before formatting..?

Comment: You forgot "init" when allocating NSDateFormatter..

Comment: What is printed in your log? converted date string?

Comment: Heres the NSLog before format - 2013-10-24 06:01:28 +0000This is your date log

Comment: How do i check to see if the datestamp is proper or not. The date I'm saving the the entity attribute datestamp is basically what comes from [NSDate date];

Comment: Added init to NSDateFormatter, but no change to error

Comment: are you sure your dIncome.datestamp is NSDate? check it use [dIncome.datestamp isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]

Comment: Im pulling the datestamp attribute from the entity DIncome, its a raw unformatted date from NSDate. I request the datestamp and I want to format it to MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss to I can display it in a table view cell

Comment: In my data model I have the attribute datestamp "type" set to date

Comment: On which line exactly do you get the error message?

Comment: This is the line I'm getting the error - NSString *formattedDateString = [formateDateString stringFromDate:dIncome.datestamp];

Comment: you may create a NSDate* date = [NSdate date]; and pass it to your method, if it works, then you should check your model

Comment: Jing, I added [dIncome.datestamp isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] and ran the app but did not see anything different happen. Not is my log and nothing that confirmed the dncome.datestamp was a string or a date

Comment: Ok, passing *date from [NSDate *date] to my method made everything work. But I need to get that date from my data model. When I send data  to my data model I'm sending [NSDate *date] with each record as they are saved, So why wouldn't the date come back in the same format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to fix this issue is to change the type for your attribute datestamp from "date" to "string, You will need to format the date how you want it to display before you send it to your data model. Of course this doesn't explain why the datestamp was having an issue when you were pulling it back out of the database. It is in he same formate as when it went in.